# Jmockit: impossible to use returns() with collections and multiple calls?

Tags: jmockit

The function I want to mock:

```
class Bar {
  public Set<Foo> getFoos();
}
```

The code under test:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  Bar bar = computeBar();
  for (Foo f : bar.getFoos()) {
    // code
  }
}
```

Expectations block:

```
new Expectations() {{
  bar.getFoos();
  returns(/* what should I put here?? */);
}};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either write

```
new Expectations() {{ bar.getFoos(); returns(foo1, foo2, foo3); }};
```

to return a single set, or

```
final Set<Foo> foos1 = new HashSet<Foo>(asList(foo1, foo2));
final Set<Foo> foos2 = new HashSet<Foo>(asList(foo3, foo4, foo5));
new Expectations() {{ bar.getFoos(); returns(foos1, foos2); }};
```

to return a sequence of sets.

Comment: Thanks, but you misunderstood my question. What you suggest would return the same values each time `bar.getFoos()` is called, but  what if I wanted to return different values for each time. That would mean calling `returns(Set<Foot> s1, Set<Foo> s2)`. But ideally, I should be able to pass any number of sets to the `returns` function.

I can do that with primitive types, by calling `returns(array of ints)`, but I can't do that with `Sets` because I can't create an array of generic collections.

Comment: Basically, what I'm asking is how to make the test expectations as dynamically as possible. Then I'd write a single parametrized test and would pass different parameters to it.

Comment: @kai I edited the answer; the recording API is very flexible, and will accept anything that can be converted to one or more sets of `Foo`.